# Add text to a table up to a certain number

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a table that I would like to populate with numbers 1 through max, where max can be any number greater than 1 but up to the total number of cells in the table. I am running into to problems that are probably really easy, but I am not just getting:
Stop adding numbers to the table once the max value is reached
Be able to start at a different location (like, the third column in on the first row)

I can get the numbers to populate, but not stop at the max number. I have tried putting the iterator at all levels of the for loop, but I can't achieve my results.

Here is my code so far:

```
from docx import Document

document_name = 'table_loop_test.docx'
document = Document('template.docx')

table = document.add_table(cols=7, rows=5)

iterator = 1
max = 30

while iterator <= max:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            cell.text = f'{iterator}'
            iterator += 1

document.save(document_name)

try:
    subprocess.check_output('open ' + document_name, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    print(exc.output).decode('utf-8')
```

I would think it would stop at 30, but it just keeps on going! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I guess it's because your 2 for-loops don't depend on your `max` variable. You need to do a check *inside* your for-loops that `iterator` hasn't incremented above `max`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One iteration of your while loop will go through the **entire** nested for loop you created. Instead of using the while loop, you can add a condition to break the both for loops.

```
for row in table.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        cell.text = f'{iterator}'
        iterator += 1
        if iterator > max_cell:
            break
    else:
        continue
    break
```

I always feel funny aobut using for-else loops since I can't remember when `else` is excecuted, so an alternative is to use `return` in a function:

```
def make_table(max_cell):
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            cell.text = f'{iterator}'
            iterator += 1
            if iterator > max:
                return
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment to have your for-loops depend on the `max`, a solution could be the following:

```
for row in table.rows:
    for cell in row.cells:
        if iterator <= max:
            cell.text = f'{iterator}'
            iterator += 1
```

This can be made more efficient by adding a condition to `break` if the `iterator` value is greater than or equal to the `max`, to prevent the for-loops from executing after the `max` value is passed.

Comment: That is beautiful. It works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @giffysquid I'm glad it worked :) If this solves you problem, please mark it as the Selected Answer

Comment: would you mind explaining more what you mean by using `break`? I am new to Python, but am interested in making it as efficient as possible. Thanks again

Comment: @giffysquid Using a `break` statement will cause the for-loop in which it is called to stop. This would optimize our code a bit, since we don't care to continue iterating through the loops if `iterator > max`. We would need 2 `break` statements--one to break out of the inner loop, and then one to break out of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put:

```
if iterator > max:
    break
```

in both of your for-loops